# Custom currency format based on another cell value

Tags: vba, excel

In cell A1 i might have one of the following currencies "EUR", "USD" or "RON". 
In cell B1 i have the following custom cell format:  "EUR"  * 0.00"/mt"

Can anyone help in telling me how can i set the format in cell B1 to **adapt** taking into account the value from A1. The code must run only at workbook.open

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the following Event Macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A1 As Range, B1 As Range, BaseFormat As String
    Dim temp As String

    Set A1 = Range("A1")
    Set B1 = Range("B1")
    BaseFormat = """EUR"" * 0.00""/mt"""
    If Intersect(A1, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    temp = A1.Value
    B1.NumberFormat = Replace(BaseFormat, "EUR", temp)
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

*(to run this only at workbook open, have the Workbook Open macro re-assert the value in **A1** and then disable events)*